# Inserting an image node between text on click

Tags: javascript, insert, cursor

I am working on moving images, but there can be text and other images also i can not use caret. So how can I use mouse/tap event to insert the node at current mouse position?

I have created a fiddle

```
    $("#box").mousemove(function(event) {
  $('img').css('left',event.pageX-20);
  $('img').css('top',event.pageY-20);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D9nEw/

Also The image should become part of text. I mean where ever the image will be inserted the content should not be under the image but move along side the image.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

Example implementation: [<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/3wuAd/).

Steps taken:

1. Add a class to the `movable` image to recognize it `class="movable"`
2. Use this image as the *cursor*: `$('img.mover')`
3. On `click`, add a `clone` of the `img` to the `body` and set it's position using `event.pageX`, `event.pageY` and remove class `mover`:

```js
$('#box').click(function(ev){
 $('img.mover').clone()
  .removeClass('mover')
  .appendTo('body')
  .css('display', 'absolute')
  .css('left', ev.pageX-20)
  .css('top', ev.pageY-20);
 });
```

You can add clones of the `img` to the `body` or to `#box`, but the element will be placed *relative* to the closest parent which has `position: relative` (which is the `body` in this case).

Comment: Actually my mistake to not explaining the problem fully. The image should become part of text. I mean where ever the image will be inserted the content should not be under the image but move along side the image.